# Observe progress of Data download in Swift?

Tags: swift, download, progress, observers

I need to cache data that I receive from an remote url to a local URL. I am able to do this successfully with:

`let dataToCache = try Data(contentsOf: url)
 try dataToCache.write(to: cacheURL)`

But I was wondering if there is some type of observer I can use to display a progress view as the data is written?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use `Data(contentsOf: url)` to make synchronous request for urls that are not local resources. You should use `URLSession`.To observe the progress you need to set urlsessiondownloaddelegate  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsessiondownloaddelegate and to monitor the progress, use the method

```
func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask, didWriteData bytesWritten: Int64, totalBytesWritten: Int64, totalBytesExpectedToWrite: Int64)
```

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsessiondownloaddelegate/1409408-urlsession